# What is the problem in the following code?

Tags: odoo-13

I want to generate auto generate book fine of 10% of book cost. I have written the following code but nothing happens. No error comes and not working. book_cost field is in book module.
Please check code.

```
   issue_date = fields.Date('Issue Date', required=True, tracking=True)
    due_date = fields.Date('Due Date', required=True, tracking=True)
    book_ids = fields.Many2many('odooschool.library.books','tch_book_rel','book_name','teacher_id','Issued Books')
    sequence = fields.Integer('sequence')
    fine_amount = fields.Char('Fine Amount', compute='_get_cost_details')
    submission_date = fields.Date.today()
    price = fields.Char('Price')
  

    @api.depends('due_date','book_ids.book_cost')
    def _get_cost_details(self):
        market_multiplier = 0
        date_return = fields.Date()
        for rec in self:
            fine_amount = 0
            if rec.due_date and rec.submission_date and rec.due_date > rec.submission_date:
                date_return = (rec.due_date - rec.submission_date)
                market_multiplier = int(decimal.Decimal('0.10'))
                fine_amount = rec.book_ids.book_cost * market_multiplier
            rec.fine_amount += rec.fine_amount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you replace

```
 submission_date = fields.Date.today()
```

by

```
submission_date = fields.Date(default= fields.Date.today)
```

That will be work. Cause the submission_date in your code is always the starting date of Odoo server.

Regards